# Center AND Right Align

Tags: html, css, ms-word, center, right-align

In many weighty and serious tomes, particularly those published by the UK's venerable **Her Majesty's Stationery Office** (HMSO), one sees a great number of tables.

Often if the column contains numeric data, not only is it **centred** in the column, but also **right aligned** on that centre point, such that the **last** digit of the number is the entity that is centred. This layout is probably dictated by HMSO style rules.

I happen to have before me page 336 of *History of the Second World War - United Kingdom Military Series - The War at Sea 1939-1945 - Volume I - The Defensive*, and I find thereon a table matching the above description.

Using old-fashioned letterpress, or even in hot metal, it's admittedly totally manual and tedious, but relatively straightforward -- just use more or less leading until it lines up.

But I would like to know if it can it be done with Microsoft Word **and/or** HTML/CSS, preferably both.

Comment: Are you talking the first edition or the third edition of *History of the Second World War - United Kingdom Military Series - The War at Sea 1939-1945 - Volume I - The Defensive*. Please be precise so I know exactly where to look.

Comment: First edition 1954

Comment: I was being sarcastic. I don't just happen to have that book lying around in 2 versions. Does my answer below solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, many thanks, it is a solution, and I should have thought of that myself, as I have been using CSS since it was a twinkle in the eye of the internet. It must be old age.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be accomplished in HTML/CSS by wrapping the text with a centered inline-block element:

```css
.wrap {
  text-align:right;
  border: 3px dotted blue;  
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  border: 10px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    Line 1 asddsa<br>
    Line 2 asdasdf<br>
    Line 3 asdfasdfasdf<br>
    Line 4 dsdf<br>
    Line 5<br>
    Line 6 s
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can you do this inside a <TD> tag

Comment: @PirateApp You can do it exactly the same way as I did in this answer. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/vwkjp3zq/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Enriching @casgage's answer:
If you are trying to do this with different rows in the same table (i.e. the values are in different cells from the same column), you need to set a min-width value for the `.wrap` class. The min-width must be a value that makes all the wrapping containers of the same size. Using the examples from the other answer:

```
.wrap {
    text-align: right;
    border: 2px dotted blue;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 150px;
}
.container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 500px;
    padding: 5px;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td className="container">
            <div className="wrap">
                Line 1 asddsa
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="container">
            <div className="wrap">
                Line 2 asdasdf
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="container">
            <div className="wrap">
                Line 3 asdfasdfasdf
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="container">
            <div className="wrap">
                Line 4 dsdf
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="container">
            <div className="wrap">
                Line 5
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="container">
            <div className="wrap">
                Line 6 s
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```